# How does the structure of a Luk-Vuillemin multiplier differ from a Wallace or Dadda multiplier?

Tags: math, multiplication, circuit

I've read that Luk-Vuillemin multipliers are similar to Wallace multipliers but partition their inputs in a different way. How exactly does this partitioning work, how does it change the structure of the multiplier, and why does it give it a more regular structure which is preferred for fabrication?

Comment: Interesting question, but I think you'll need to find a forum which is specifically devoted to computer engineering. Take a look at the list of Stackexchange sites.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try the computer science exchange.